# Select SUM con distintos LIKE anidar query

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta para a mi base de datos donde pregunto la cantidad movida de una recepta a distintas areas

```
 SELECT COALESCE(SUM(d.Cantidad), 0)  as total FROM details AS d
 LEFT JOIN details_descripcion AS de ON de.id_descripcion d.id_descripcion
 WHERE d.operacion ='0001' AND d.Item='1' AND de.area_to LIKE '%-RETAILS' 
 AND de.area_from LIKE 'BODEGA%' AND d.status='Y' AND d.date BETWEEN '2019-11-12' AND '2019-12-11'
 GROUP BY d.Item ORDER BY d.Item +0 DESC
```

Pero en el caso que si quiero saber una distinta área debo volver hacer la misma consulta, pero con diferente `LIKE`

Hay alguna forma de poder anidar o resumir la query obteniendo diferentes SUM `SELECT` con `LIKE` distintos?

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|Bodega_to_Retails  | Area1_to_bodega | Area2_to_bodega |
--------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|         5000      |       8000      |      4000       |  
|-------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
```

Algo asi seria mi resultado esperado. Espero haberme explicado bien

Comment: y agregar un or y agrupar por arean no sirve porque?

Comment: @gbianchi y como distingo las diferentes SUM de cada area?

Comment: Precisamente agrupando :) ... ¿nos pasas la estructura de la base de datos y algún dato de muestra para probar la consulta? Ya sabes phpMyAdmin/Exportar

Comment: De paso te comento que ese query esta mal. Esa clausula group by no hace absolutamente nada, porque no hay nada que agrupar. Lo mismo para orden. Todo eso esta obsoleto porque en tu where pusiste d.Item='1'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que buscas es una suma condicional, es decir un `SUM()` que considere las condiciones apropiadas para cada caso a la hora de sumar, por ejemplo para obtener los movimientos desde la bodega a retails, podrías hacer algo así:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(
                  CASE WHEN de.area_from LIKE 'BODEGA%' 
                       AND de.area_to LIKE '%-RETAILS' 
                       THEN d.Cantidad 
                       ELSE 0 END
                    ), 0) as Bodega_to_Retails,

       COALESCE(SUM(d.Cantidad), 0)  as total 

       FROM details AS d
       LEFT JOIN details_descripcion AS de 
            ON de.id_descripcion d.id_descripcion
       WHERE d.operacion ='0001' 
             AND d.Item='1' 
             AND d.status='Y' 
             AND d.date BETWEEN '2019-11-12' AND '2019-12-11'
```

Como puedes ver, hemos trasladado tu filtro original del `WHERE` al `SUM` mediante un `CASE` para ver si sumamos en caso de cumplirse la condición. Puedes de esta forma ir agregando más columnas de total, obviamente el `WHERE` debe incluir todos los casos. Y de paso, es cierto lo que dice Gonzalo, tu `GROUP BY` no tiene sentido ya que estas buscando un total general, a menos que posteriormente quieras estos totales por `Item`.

Comment: Gracias x tu respuesta, consulta si yo deseo agregar otra area
Ejemplo `de.area_from LIKE 'Area1%' AND de.area_to LIKE '%-BODEGA'`
Deberia agregar un nuevo `CASE`?

Comment: Exactamente, un nuevo sum +  case.

Comment: Si no es mucha molestia podria agregar un ejemplo con una distinta area. Intento hacerlo y me muestra un error de `syntax`

Comment: El patrón que debes respetar es `COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN <Condicion> THEN d.Cantidad  ELSE 0 END), 0)`, lo que varía es `<Condicion>`

Comment: Muchas gracias!